# Oracle Apex intelligent select list

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am building a system which require creating drop down select list. However I would like to add some more information for end user. So if I have :

```
Select client_name d, client r from clients_db
```

I would like to build something like this that is client_status = 'vip' then background of this element on drop down list is red. I am aware that I can use concat and add text value but this is not something system require.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Dynamic Actions" for it task. See http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/apex/r41/dynactions/dynactions.htm